# Can't find a way to send post request

Tags: javascript, jquery

So my problem is that I'm tying to get the `stroke` values to send as a post request just like my script currently does the `points`attribute values in the post request... `l: (JSON.stringify(line))` << Just like that in the post request but I need it to do the `stroke` values. So if it's possible to use something like `c: (JSON.stringify(stroke))`

I want to match the lines with their stroke colors and send the request with the color just like the line.

The stroke value is inside the `style` attribute of that SVG. Here's a image showing exactly what I need to log just like it does the `points`.

[image]

So yeah, simply parse and send it like it does the `points` values..

I've tried making a const just like the `LINES` but no luck.

```
xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://colorillo.com/blqu.inline.svg");
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
this.responseText.trim(),
"image/svg+xml"
);
const Lines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'), pl => 
pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(pair => 
pair.split(',').map(Number)));

Lines.forEach(line => $.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", {
                l: (JSON.stringify(line)), 
                w: ("1"),
                c: (JSON.stringify(Stroke)), //<<<< MY ERROR IS HERE!!!
                o: ("75"),
                f: ("1"),
                _: ("false")
            }));
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @GrafiCode, ``c: (JSON.stringify(Stroke)), //<<<< MY ERROR IS HERE!!!`` in my script. Near the post request.

Comment: In Google's console. Says stroke is not defined. Please help me.

Comment: Where did `Stroke` come from? It is not defined anywhere, that's why you get the `undefined` error

Comment: ``const Lines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'), pl => 
pl.getAttribute('style')``  This is the piece I had trying to define ``stroke`` since the stroke values are in the ``style`` attribute.

Comment: if you `console.log(Lines)` before looping it with forEach, what's the output?

Comment: When I logged ``style`` it gave me some element in google's console. It contained the stroke value inside of it, but I just need the stroke values only and not the rest like the ``fill`` values and ``stroke-width`` values for a example. So only the stroke values.. Which is a hex value.

Comment: When I log lines. This is what it gets in console. https://gyazo.com/9dd127450f8febd014bfb501f683863f

Comment: is there anyway I can get those values just like it does the ``l: (JSON.stringify(line))`` in the post request. That's all I need really.

Comment: After that my problem will be settled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, just search the array for 'stroke' like this:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3jea7p6n/)**

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://colorillo.com/blqu.inline.svg");
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
        this.responseText.trim(),
        "image/svg+xml"
    );
    let output = [];
    // Get all polylines as strings
    let lines = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline');
    // Loop over all lines
    for(let line of lines) {
        //Define more vars here...
        //Often times you can just use something like below and don't need to put it in the loop.
        let stroke = null; //See Bruce'es comment (rgb() as output): line.style.stroke;
        let opacity = line.style.opacity;
        let strokeWidth = line.style.strokeWidth;

        // Loop over all styles of this line (output same as input [hex])
        for(let style of line.getAttribute('style').split(';')) {
            // Get name & value
            let valueOffset = style.indexOf(':');
            // Check if name equal to 'stroke'
            let value = style.substr(valueOffset + 1).trim()
            switch(style.substr(0, valueOffset).trim()) {
                case 'stroke':
                    // Save stroke value
                    stroke = value;
                    // Break out of the loop (we don't have to search further)
                    break;
            }
        }
        output.push({
            l: (JSON.stringify(line.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(pair => pair.split(',').map(Number)))),
            w: (strokeWidth),
            c: (stroke),
            o: (opacity),
            f: ("1"),
            _: ("false")
        });
    }
    $.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", output);
});
xhr.send();
```

Hope this helps. *-Minding*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195964/discussion-on-answer-by-minding-cant-find-a-way-to-send-post-request).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be because you're calling JSON.stringify() inside a JSON object. Try this instead:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "http://colorillo.com/blqu.inline.svg");
xhr.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const xmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
        this.responseText.trim(),
        "image/svg+xml"
    );
    const Lines = Array.from(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('polyline'), pl =>
        pl.getAttribute('points').split(' ').map(pair =>
            pair.split(',').map(Number)));
    Lines.forEach(line => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(line));
        $.post("/draw.php?ing=_index", {
            l: ("foo"),
            w: ("1"),
            c: ("#000000"),
            o: ("75"),
            f: ("1"),
            _: ("false")
        });
    });
});
xhr.send();
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I need. I need it send the post request with the stroke values just like it does with ``l: (JSON.stringify(line))``

Comment: I've edited my code explaining a bit better in the top paragraph.

Comment: If you need me to explain a bit more details. I will try my very best.